# model validate only for create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

There's a way of validate a field only for the create action ?

Supose,

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password

  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

in that case the password field will be required to save anything to db `@client.save`

What I want is that the password must be present only for: create the client and update the password, any other field update doesn't need password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the following to your validation.

> on: :create

For your code it will be

> validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 } , on: :create

If you want the validation for multiple action then you can provide array of symbols.

> On : [:create ,:edit]